# Building a form with many2many association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, join, symfony-3.2

I have a Many2Many association between a `Project` entity and a `User`; a project can have man participants (users) and a user can participate to many projects. I have a join table, because I want to save additional data.

The entity representing the join table looks like this:

```
class ProjectParticipants {
  /** @ORM\ManytoOne(targetEntity("Project", inversedBy="projectParticipants")) */
  private $project;

  /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity("User", inversedBy="ProjectParticipants")) */
  private $participant;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") */
  private $hasJoined;
}
```

The Project Entity has the following association with ProjectParticipants:

```
class Project {
  /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectParticipants", mappedBy="project") */
  private $projectParticipants;
}
```

The User Entity has the following association with ProjectParticipants:

```
class User
  /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectParticipants", mappedBy="participant") */
  private $projectParticipants;
}
```

Now I have a form in which a Project Object can be made. It has a with some users (multiselectbox) in it whom can be added to the project. **The question now is, how should the form (using the Symfony (v.3.2.7.) form component) be built to get the selected Users and the current Project in the ProjectParticipants association?**

```
$builder->add(...)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this **complete example** shows what exactly you're trying to do. [Many-to-many association example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/toza/many-to-many-association-example-in-symfony)

Comment: I don't think that link answers the OP's question; it just shows three completely separate forms, while OP apparently needs the Project form to contain a way to add Users to it. Which would normally be possible by adding an EntityType to Project's form, if there wasn't a separate association class introducing a level of indirection. This is the same problem I am looking an answer for... :(